# Regex Split string of arithmetic expression into list with its operators and numbers (decimal included)

Tags: python, regex, list, arithmetic-expressions

I have made this code, but i don't think it's the best way.

```
import re
notation = "41*(5.5+6-(8/2^3)-7)-1"
n2 = [x[0] for x in re.findall(r"(\d+(\.\d+)?)",notation)]
n2.reverse()
m = []
x = True

for z in notation:
    if z.isdigit() and x:
        m.append(n2.pop())
        x = False
    if not z.isdigit() and z != ".": 
        m.append(z)
        x = True
```

The expected output is:

> m = ['41', '*', '(', '5.5', '+', '6', '-', '(', '8', '/', '2', '^', '3', ')', '-', '7', ')', '-', '1']

I think this code has a kind of hardcoding, my doubt is how would you make it in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using regex findall, you can get your desired result!

**Regex:**

```
re.findall('[0-9.]+|.',m)
```

therefore,

```
>>> import re
>>> notation  = '41*(5.5+6-(8/2^3)-7)-1'
>>> m = re.findall('[0-9.]+|.',notation )
>>> print m
['41', '*', '(', '5.5', '+', '6', '-', '(', '8', '/', '2', '^', '3', ')', '-', '7', ')', '-', '1']
```

If you are specific about your symbols `+\-*^/()` then you can use

```
>>> m = re.findall('[0-9.]+|[+\-*^/()]',notation)
>>> print m
['41', '*', '(', '5.5', '+', '6', '-', '(', '8', '/', '2', '^', '3', ')', '-', '7', ')', '-', '1']
```

will give you the desired result!

Hope it helps!

Comment: The `.` in the regular expression will catch everything, even non-arithmetic characters, so if your string has for example `?` or `!` it will be caught, that's why I purposely made a character class `[+\-*^/()]`  instead of `.`

Comment: I've added the edit! In the first case, any notation and number will be matched to a list and in the second is restricted to match only the specified ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it with [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), with [this](https://regex101.com/r/pSP2Kg/1) `re` expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> m =[]
>>> s = "41*(5.5+6-(8/2^3)-7)-1"
>>> for match in re.finditer(r'[+\-*^/()]|[0-9.]+', s):
        if match:
            m.append(match.group(0))


>>> m
['41', '*', '(', '5.5', '+', '6', '-', '(', '8', '/', '2', '^', '3', ')', '-', '7', ')', '-', '1']
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I think it looks better like this: 
`m = [mt.group(0) for mt in re.finditer(r'[+\-*^/()]|([0-9.]+)', s)]`

Comment: @NapoleónCortés, up to you, I just put it simpler for your understanding, but I'm wondering about the downvote as I don't see any comments? :-O

Comment: I put a +1 vote but my profile doesn't have the level for it to count, I don't know why you got that downvote :O

Answer (score 0):

Use [*re.findall*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with a regex designed to find either *numbers* or *operators*.

- The number pattern is `[0-9.]+` which gets all digits and decimal points.
- An single-character operator pattern is `[*/+\-\^]` which gets multiplication, division, addition, subtraction (escaped because `-` is a special regex character), and exponentation (also escaped because `-` is a special regex character).

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> notation = "41*(5.5+6-(8/2^3)-7)-1"
>>> re.findall(r'[0-9.]+|[*/+\-\^]', notation)
['41', '*', '5.5', '+', '6', '-', '8', '/', '2', '^', '3', '-', '7', '-', '1']
```

The number pattern can be further refined to look for a maximum of a single decimal place. `(?:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|(?:[0-9]+\.)|(?:\.?[0-9]+)`.  This can parse the numbers in `3.14 + 42. + .707 + 6`.

To handle multi-character operators, put them first in a chain (to prevent the single character from matching first).  For example, `(?:\*\*|\*|/|\+|\-)` would parse the operators in `2 ** 5 / 6 + 7 * 3 - 1`.

Hope this helps you working your lexer experiments :-)

Comment: thanks! Useful information, the only thing is that I needed also the "()" characters.